# Async Timer Triggered Function

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to create a function on a TimerTrigger, that will run asynchronously? In other words, a function that will not cause the trigger to wait for completion, before scheduling the next execution?

We have a scenario where we need to schedule a function execution every 5 seconds. Most executions take less than a second to complete, but occasionally, they can take longer (more than 5 seconds). In those situations, we still want our 5-second schedule to kick in, even though that would cause parallel executions.

According to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#scheduling):

> If your function execution takes longer than the timer interval, another execution won't be triggered until after the current invocation completes. The next execution is scheduled after the current execution completes.

What I'm looking for, is a possible way to avoid delaying the next execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a queue would likely address your issue and is the most common async processing pattern.  Instead of the timer function processing the request have the request passed on as a message to a storage queue when the timer trigger is executed. A second function then processes the actual request without impacting any execution times on the timer function.

So essentially timer trigger -> message -> queue trigger . More details on azure function storage queue triggers can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---example

Comment: Funny thing is, our timer triggered function is already popping items off of a queue manually. It does this conditionally, though, as we have a requirement never to process more than 4 messages in parallel. Unfortunately, using a queue based architecture together with app consumption plan, there seems to be no way to guarantee that we will never have more than 4 simultaneous executions. In the timer-based approach, we can check whether the limit has been reached, before popping a new message off the queue for processing.

Comment: I see your predicament. There are some dials you can use to control message processing concurrency in functions.  You might be able to get way with setting the batch size to 4 so no more then 4 queue messages will be handled at a time and then set WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT=1 to ensure there is only ever one instance running (batchsize is per instance). More details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---concurrency . Borders on hacky IMO but with this you may be able to achieve what you're looking for.